# shell script to groovy script using gant

Tags: shell, grails, ant, groovy, gant

I have written a shell script with commands like:

```
version=$1;

sed -i 's/def version = ".*"/def version = "'$version'"/' $file;

grails package-plugin;

echo -n 'Enter description of new version: ';

read desc;

git commit -m "$desc";
```

I want to convert it into a `groovy script` i.e, to create a custom grails-command that does the same thing, using `GANT`.

I searched a lot. But, I'm unable to find the proper methods in Apache Ant API to run a linux command like above.

Please suggest me a solution to my shell-script code with equivalent GANT script

Atleast suggest me `where to start with` to achieve my task.

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: It is very troublesome using the Apache Ant API:

http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

Comment: Have you had a look at [http://www.gradle.org/](gradle)?

Comment: @lucke84 : can't it be done without using gradle

Comment: I guess so, but you're trying to do ant tasks in groovy, and gradle simply do the job.

Comment: Actually, I wanna do it without using gradle .. I mean just by using in-built `ant` object like `ant.mkdir()`. Help me in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at last, I have figured it out how to perform the above said task.

Thanx to [Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts) documentation and [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) tasks manual . .

After taking a whole day time, I observed that for any task to be performed:

1. one can refer to Apache Ant manual first,
2. Find it in the index,
3. and then knowing its usage along with necessary arguments and examples given in XML,
4. Then observe how XML syntax is converted to corresponding Groovy script i.e., GANT script

   For e.g., observe the [mkdir](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html) task and its corresponding usage in grails doc [example](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts) i.e., use `ant` variable, then `.` `task-name` `[ arguments-map ]`
5. For those shell commands which don't have a direct task in Apache Ant manual, use `exec()` to run the command
6. That's it ... task complete :)